# How can I roll back bad changes to a local git repository?

Tags: git, github, dvcs

I am new to git, and I am running into one big issue.  Namely how to revert a repository back to a good state if I do something wrong.  I have seen how to use 'git revert' to make changes that undo previous changes, and I have read quite a few of the questions on stackoverflow and related locations, but I haven't found a simple way to simply say "put my local repository bits back to exactly what they were before I did X" where X may be a commit, merge, or other repository operation.

Long Story:

This bit me particularly hard today when I was trying to setup a subtree branch for a third-party dependency (Jasmine) following the steps in the ProGit book on [Subtree Merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html).  I followed the steps and setup a local repository with a branch that tracked a remote Jasmine repository.  Then I connected this up using read-tree to a subdirectory in my probject and all was good.  Unfortunately the Jasmine branch contained a submodule reference to a non-public URL and when I tried to fix this up I made the changes (and commits) on the branch I had tracking the remote repository.  No matter what I did to try to revert these commits/changes, my 'git push' commands couldn't work anymore because the repository thought I had changes to the Jasmine code and was trying to push them back through the public URL I was tracking.

Summary: I screwed up part of my respository and could not figure out how to get it back in the pristine condition it was in before I issued the commands caused by my git newbie status.

Is there anyway to rollback the entire repository a few commits/changes or do I just have to clone it again and start over when this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use git-reflog

```
git reflog
```

Spot the revision that you want to go back to

```
git reset HEAD@{n}
```

(replacing n by the proper number)

Perhaps `git reset --hard` after that if you have unclean work tree; be very careful as *those* won't be restoreable)

Comment: +1.  I just wanted to point out that you can specify any commit you want in `git reset`, not just ones from `git reflog`.  A commit from his regular `git log` will probably suffice in this case.